# How do I program an AVR Raven with Linux or a Mac?

Tags: avr, linux

[This tutorial](http://www.sics.se/%7Eadam/contiki/docs-uipv6/a01107.html) starts with programming the Ravens and Jackdaw with a Windows box.  Can I do those initial steps with a Linux or OS X machine instead?  If so, how?  Is there any risk of bricking the hardware if I just try?

I have a USB JTAG ICE MKii clone, which is supposed to work for this.

I'm totally new to AVR, but very experienced with C/C++ programming on Linux or OS X, up to and including kernel programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux, you'd probably use [`avrdude`](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) to program them. It supports most programmers and most AVR chips. The main thing to watch out for, is that I think you need to use `avr-objcopy` to extract the data from the 'ELF' binary files, you can't program the 'ELF' directly with avrdude.

---

Random googling for avr-objcopy / avrdude commandlines comes up with this, which looks like it might work:

```
# create demo.bin from demo.elf
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O binary demo.elf demo.bin

# program demo.bin to the 'flash' memory in an 'atmega128' chip,
# using a 'stk200' programmer connected to the 'lpt1' port on your computer
avrdude -p atmega128 -c stk200 -P lpt1 -U flash:w:demo.bin:r
```

Comment: Ok.  Do you know the exact avr-objcopy incantation to do that splitting?  I've figured out quite a bit of the avrdude part, I think, but not what the right way of splitting the ELF files is.

Comment: Did some random googling, above is what I found

Comment: Thanks, that got me most of the way.  For the record, you also have to extract the eeprom section from the elf files, and of course set the fuses right.

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't programmed eeprom from the PC before (I've always had my software program its own eeprom), so I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing projects on Linux, do some searching for a good Makefile that supports avr-gcc and avrdude. You should then just have to edit the Makefile to specify your hardware and source files and you're away.

To build a binary you generally just call `make`, to program a device is often `make program` and sometimes `make fuse` to set the fuses on the AVR.

I've used [Mfile](http://www.sax.de/~joerg/mfile/) for generating Makefiles on Windows, but it looks like they support *nix also.

Answer (score 2):

Avrdude works just fine on OSX too. Just,

```
port install avrdude avr-gcc avr-binutils avr-gdb avr-libc
```

And you're ready to do everything that WinAVR does.